# Scalar relationships between the coordinates of two rotated coordinate systems

Tags: education, coordinate-systems, rotations

I'm wondering how come between the coordinate system $\xi \eta$, rotated -45° with respect to $x y$ coordinate system, and the $xy$ coordinate system there are the [following relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Hyperbola_with_equation_y_=_A/x):

$$x = \frac{\xi + \eta}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$y = \frac{-\xi + \eta}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This seems like a good opportunity to learn by exploring: draw some diagrams and see how these relationships come from certain right triangles.

Comment: Hello @amd, I followed your suggestion, and now it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you one way to look at at.  The coordinate system of the $xy$ axis are determined by the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.  What this means is any point $(a,b)$ can be expressed as a linear combination $$\left(\begin{matrix} a \\ b \end{matrix}\right)= a\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right) +b\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right) = ax+by$$

But what happens to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ after a $-45^o$ rotation? By drawing a picture, using the "special right triangles" where the internal angle is $45^o$, and naming the coordinates after rotation $\xi$ and $\eta$, we see that
$$ x = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right) \to \left(\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{matrix}\right) = \xi  $$
and 
$$ y = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right) \to \left(\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{matrix}\right)= \eta  $$

We can see the identities in your question applied to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ directly from the 2 equations, since
$$ \frac{\xi + \eta}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left[ \left(\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{matrix}\right) + \left(\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{matrix}\right)  \right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{matrix}\right) =  \left(\begin{matrix} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right) =  \left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right) = x $$
and almost identical calculation for $y$

Comment: Hello @NazimJ, good explanation.